# Validate test results in Protractor (non "expect" function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Help me please to find way to validate test result in *Protractor* not from "*expect*" function.

I have such code:

```
describe("The 'toEqual' matcher", function() {

it("works for simple literals and variables", function() {
    expect(12).toEqual(12);

    if (this.results_.failedCount === 0) {
        console.log("This test passed")
    }
    else{
        console.log("This test failed")
    }
});});
```

but when I execute this test I have such message:

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'failedCount' of undefined.
```

May be you know such another solution to fix my problem?

Thanks for support.

Comment: What's version of jasmine? 1.x or 2.x? There are breaking changes with this. inside it() functions in jasmine 2.x

Comment: I use Jasmine "version": "2.4.1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be counting passes and failures yourself directly in the test. Let the protractor and jasmine runner worry about it. If you need to have a control over it, look into making a [jasmine reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html) or using one of the many existing, like the [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter), for instance.

Comment: It really work! I use  [jasmine reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html), it have function "result.status == "passed". Thank you for help!